# Use .htacess to redirect all files in a specific folder to a script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to use htacess to redirect the following examples:

```
www.site.com/downloads/file1.txt
www.site.com/downloads/folder/file2.txt
```

to

```
www.site.com/download?file=file1.txt
www.site.com/download?file=folder/file2.txt
```

Ignore that there are slashes in the query string for the sake of the example.

Comment: Webmasters normally do the opposite of what you're doing... [See SEO 2.0 | Top 10 Fatal URL Design Mistakes](http://seo2.0.onreact.com/top-10-fatal-url-design-mistakes)

Comment: It's not what I want to do, I'd prefer clean URL's, I just haven't found a way to do it with a custom framework I'm stuck with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for that.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/downloads/(.+)" "/download?file=$1" [R=301,L]
```

Set the proper [HTTP status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for the rewrite action (301 - permanent, 307 - temporary).

As I never used mod_rewrite in .htacces, you may need to try out some more combinations. Maybe the directory name needs to be removed from the regular expression, as it is already clear from the .htaccess context - the manual should help.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/downloads/(.*) /download?file=$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

```
301 - Moved Permanently
The resource has permanently moved to a different URI.
```

Resources:

HTTP Status Codes
http://www.helpwithpcs.com/courses/html/html_http_status_codes.htm#300

Apache mod_rewrite
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html